# Manually add local file to the Downloads app

Tags: android, download, download-manager

My app needs to download files, I was looking into DownloadManager, however it has some limitations that don't suit my case (authentication, naming scheme, verification), so I made my custom download engine.

Is it possible to manually add a file downloaded with my engine (thus by using a local URL) to the list in the Downloads system app? My understanding is that list is populated by a system content provider. Is it possible to add records to it, without the DownloadManager trying to download the file?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436650/adding-to-download-list-android

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To manually add a file you need to use the DownloadManager class. I use the following to show a file in the Download app that I created locally.

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)mainActivity.getSystemService(mainActivity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(file.getName(), file.getName(), true, "application/json", file.getAbsolutePath(),file.length(),true);
```

This will make the file appear in the Downloads app on 6.0, even if the file was created locally.

Comment: The `addCompletedDownload` method has been deprecated in API 29.

Comment: any change on how this should be used? `DownloadManager` doesn't let me copy local files into Downloads. It says only `http` / `https` should be used.

Comment: Yep, broken now. Only allows HTTP/HTTPS URIs

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin Equivalent of the above answer:

```
val downloadManager =   this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(file.getName(), file.getName(), true, "application/json", file.getAbsolutePath(),file.length(),true)
```