# Android: Save local File to Downloads Folder and make it visible

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my app save files to the local Downloads folder. The Problem is, that they are not visible when using the "Downloads App" (They are visible when i use a different filemanager).

As already mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184936/5595421
it seems to be because the files weren't actually "downloaded".

So I tried to start a download with a local file Uri, what leads to illegal argument Exception because it appears that DownloadManager can only handle http Uri's.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make your files visible without downloading with the `DownloadManager`, but just notifying it using [addCompletedDownload](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#addCompletedDownload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20boolean)).

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) mService.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.addCompletedDownload(title, description, isMediaScannerScannable, mimeType, path, length, showNotification);
```

In case you'll want to disable the download notification, you would also need to add the permission for it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```