# How to save file in folder on java?

Tags: java, android, save

How can I save a file in a selected folder in Java? 
I need it like this: `storage/emulated/0/myfile.txt` 
Is there is an example?

Comment: this might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184936/12913325

Answer (score 0):

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("storage/emulated/0/myfile.txt")) {
    out.println(text);
}
```

If this is not what you want you'll have to add more details

Answer (score -1):

I have published a library that saves files, and handles everything with one line of code only, you can find it here along with its documentation

[Github repository](https://github.com/rasmi-aw/StorageManager)

and the answer to your question is so easy

```
String path = FileSaver
        .get()
        .save(inputStream,"your/path","file.mp3");
```

Comment: don't post the exact same answer to multiple questions - partcularly not to promote a library/ utility you wrote