# I write a file to Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, why can't I see it via the Downloads App?

Tags: android

I write (write, not download, to be precise it is the dump of a SQLite db of my App) a file on the Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS directory.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path, "db.csv");
```

If I browse the phone with a file browser, I can see correctly the file in the

```
  /storage/emulated/0/Download
```

Directory, together with the other downloads.

But if I open the Downloads App it does not show...

What do I need to do to have the file shown in the Downloads App as well?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve your problem ? I'm having the exact same issue, it would be great if you could share the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Downloads app only shows downloads downloaded via `DownloadManager`, not all files in the directory.

Comment: How can I found my download file in `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`

Comment: @mehmet: Use DDMS. Or, mount the device's external storage on a computer using a USB cable.

Comment: No no in android, programaticly

Comment: @mehmet: I do not know what you mean by "found". You can use Java I/O, such as the `File` class, to work with files.

Comment: @rontho has a better asnwer

Comment: @CommonsWare why the files downloaded via DownloadManager does not show up in Downloads folder in Android 11?

Comment: @Aniruddha: I am uncertain how you are looking in the Downloads folder. Bear in mind that the actual act of downloading is not done by `DownloadManager` itself. Instead, it sends a message to a separate system app that does the downloading, so that can continue independently of your app. Scoped storage rules might make it so your app cannot see the download via filesystem APIs, because it was downloaded by another process rather than your own. Personally, I avoid `DownloadManager`.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. What's the alternate for `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` for SDK less than 29? Need to save files in Download folder, but `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is deprecated. Hence we cannot use `(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

Comment: @CommonsWare why would you not use DownloadManager? Any particular reasons?

Comment: @Aniruddha: "Need to save files in Download folder, but getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is deprecated" -- for "less than 29", use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. "why would you not use DownloadManager?" -- because `DownloadManager` is nearly useless. It does not support downloading to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or to user-selected locations (e.g., via the Storage Access Framework). Its API is terrible. And that was *before* the problems that people seem to encounter with `DownloadManager` and scoped storage.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone wonder how to do this, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436650/adding-to-download-list-android)

To allow the System to display you file in the "Downloads" App, you need to explicitly notify the DownloadManager that a download as been completed by using the method [`addCompletedDownload()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#addCompletedDownload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20boolean))

By using it, the system will allow your Download App to display the file you have created yourself.

Hope it will help.

**UPD**: `This method was deprecated in API level 29.`

Answer (score 2):

you just created File instance like

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path, "db.csv");
```

but the file "db.csv"  is not created yet. use

```
file.createNewFile();
```

to create the file "db.csv" really...

Comment: thanks Gopal, the file is created and it shows up in the directory, only it does not show in the Downloads App as I would expect, since i am writing it in the `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the setVisibleInDownloadsUi property.
This allows the download to be visible in the Downloads app.
See [Download.Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setVisibleInDownloadsUi(boolean))

**UPD**: `This method was deprecated in API level 29.`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)`,
look for a file in `/sdcard/Android/data/<package name>/files/Download`. In emulator it can be found in `Device File Explorer`.

[image]

If you use `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)`, then you can find a downloaded file in `Download` folder of `Files` application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your file to downloaded list:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.addCompletedDownload("db.csv", "my description", false, "text/csv", file.getAbsolutePath(), file.length(), false);
```