# can we open download folder via. intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager

Actually, I need to open the default Download folder from my application. Is it possible? If yes, then please provide some reference.

I am able to get the path of Download folder with the help of:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Any help will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can show the recent downloads activity with the following `Intent`

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Available since API 9

Comment: Hi Ion Aalbers, thanks for the reply. Is there any way(Intent) to pick the file from Download folder?

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta What do you want to do with this file? Open it?

Comment: Hi Ion Aalbers, I want to allow the user to pick the desired file from the Download folder, and upload to the server. Currently I am able to do this task with the  help of 3rd party file explorer.

Comment: Hello guys. Have you tested that on samsung phones? Because I have tested it with samsung phone (running Nugat) and it was opening a Download Histor but with empty content. The section had not any downloaded file. What I have to do to find my recent download file was to go manually to Samsung Files app and find it under Internal Storage/Downloads. Any idea why that's happening and how can I fix that on Samsung devices?

Comment: @Tzegenos it is happening because "The Downloads app only shows downloads downloaded via DownloadManager, not all files in the directory", https://stackoverflow.com/a/20472865/5222156

Comment: After writing the file, if i open the downloads folder programmatically using startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)). File is not visible. But if i open from file explorer of phone, then the file is visible. Any idea, why this is happening ?

Comment: Help!! Any way to open the specific download folder using this?

Answer (score 12):

Samsung solution:

```
public static void openDownloads(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    if (isSamsung()) {
        Intent intent = activity.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.myfiles");
        intent.setAction("samsung.myfiles.intent.action.LAUNCH_MY_FILES");
        intent.putExtra("samsung.myfiles.intent.extra.START_PATH", 
                getDownloadsFile().getPath());
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    else activity.startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
}

public static boolean isSamsung() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (manufacturer != null) return manufacturer.toLowerCase().equals("samsung");
    return false;
}

public static File getDownloadsFile() {
    return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
}
```

Found by decompiling the Samsung [My Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.myfiles) app dex and seeing how the MainActivity deals with intents.

```
public static final String MYFILES_NOTIFICATION_LAUNCH_INTENT_NAME = "samsung.myfiles.intent.action.LAUNCH_MY_FILES";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_START_PATH = "samsung.myfiles.intent.extra.START_PATH";
public static final String START_PATH = "FOLDERPATH";

if (Constant.MYFILES_NOTIFICATION_LAUNCH_INTENT_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String startNotificationPath = intent.getStringExtra(Constant.NOTIFICATION_START_PATH);
                if (startNotificationPath != null) {
                    Bundle newArgument = new Bundle();
                    newArgument.putString(Constant.START_PATH, startNotificationPath);
                    if (new File(startNotificationPath).exists()) {
                        startBrowser(513, newArgument);
                    }
                }
                intent.removeExtra(Constant.NOTIFICATION_START_PATH);
            }
```

Comment: I've been trying to open folders with the god-forsaken Samsung's FileBrowser App during the last two days. This is the only solution that worked so far. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I was struggling with it too, longer than I would like to admit. @4gus71n

Comment: This is the only acceptable answer for Samsung devices. Thank you

Comment: Np @Deepakkaku! Glad it is still helpful 5 years later! 

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem showing files in Downloads in Samsung and LG and i just added file-parameter "downloaded" for DownloadManager  and file showing in Downloads:

```
  DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(file.getName(), file.getName(), true,
                "application", file.getPath(), file.length(), true);
```

Comment: where the file. came from