# Alternate methods to access external downloads folder on sdcard android studio

Tags: java, android, storage, external

To the point. I've tried using this to a button on my app to access the sdcard downloads folder but the only thing i get in return is the sound of tapping a button and nothing more:

```
btPastaVideos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
         Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
         }
      }
    );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to open external download option?

Comment: No. I want the phone to open the download folder (external folder.. in my sdcard) when I tap on a button inside my app.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072638/fileuriexposedexception-in-android/50102119#50102119) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Comment: How can I directly open a subdirectory under download folder?