# Start another app by link android

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking

How to start A application's specific activity in B application by link?

1. Share a URI contains information about A's specific activity.
2. If a user click that link in B app, start A app's specific activity.

this is my `AndroidManifiest.xml` code.

```
 <activity android:name = ".activity.PhotoActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <data android:scheme="mine" android:host="photo"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

this is `shareURI` method.

```
 fun sendUri(videoId:String?, point:Long) {
    val sharedUri = "mine://photo?photo_id=$photoId&size=$size"

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
    intent.data = Uri.parse(sharedUri)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share URL"))

}
```

But it's not working. 
when I try to share that link, chooser does not appear.
and there's a message.

> 'All app associated with this action have been disabled, blocked, or are not installed.`

Comment: Update your question with the error that you are facing

Comment: @Sagar sorry. I have error intent.ACTION_SEND not working.
chooser is not appeared. and there's a message 'All app associated with this action have been disabled, blocked, or are not installed.'

Comment: Try to remove one of `addCategory` line to see if it works. Also try to use the same Action you define in `intent-filter`, which is `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_SEND`

Comment: @TamHuynh Thank you for your time. I tried both but still not working.

Comment: @mel.j try using intent.setDataAndType ( Uri.parse(sharedUri), "text/plain"), Instead of intent.type & intent.data

Comment: @Sagar It still not working. `val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(sharedUri), "text/plain")
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share URL"))` could you show your sample code?

Comment: @mel.j Do you see any error?

Comment: @Sagar still same message  :  'All app asociated with this action have been disabled, blocked, or are not installed.'

Comment: Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072638/fileuriexposedexception-in-android) for some details of how to implement it. Its code is written in Java though.

Comment: @Sagar Thank you for your time. but it didn't work. So I use firebase dynamic link. now it works. Anyway, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use firebase DynamicLink. 
It's very useful.