# How to open File manager navigated to specific directory in android?

Tags: android, android-file

I want to show downloaded file in File Manager by giving the **File absolute Path**.I read a  lot about it and find same thing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

**And it results** to view only recent files that has been viwed. Please guide to Open File Manager while **navigating**  it to file whose absolute path has been given.

Comment: have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072638/fileuriexposedexception-in-android/50102119#50102119) ?

Answer (score 0):

> I read a lot about it and find same thing

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has little to do with a file manager.

> Please guide to Open File Manager while navigating it to file whose absolute path has been given.

There is nothing on Android for this, sorry.

Comment: Then is there any substitution to  show downloaded file in storage folder directory.

Comment: @RaiMashhoodQadeerBhatti: I do not know what you mean by "show downloaded file in storage folder directory". There is no requirement for an Android device to have a full-fledged file manager app. The UI that you might see by default for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is part of the Storage Access Framework. That is the Android equivalent of "file save-as" and "file open" dialogs that you might find in a desktop OS, not a true file manager.

Comment: Ok I Confess  it then how can I use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`  to view only file which path I have given as uri

Comment: @RaiMashhoodQadeerBhatti: That is not supported, sorry.