# Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider

Tags: java, android, android-intent, apk

I was having some problem when trying to perform an application upgrade in Android emulator. The flow of the scenario is from an Activity, I will execute **AsyncTask A** which open up **fragment A**, then inside **AsyncTask A**, I will check if version upgrade is available.

If available and user selected "Okay" from **fragment A**, I will proceed to **AsyncTask B** to open up **fragment B** which show a message to user saying that upgrading is in process. In **AsyncTask B** *doInBackground()*, I will execute the *install()* and in *onPostExecute()*, I will show successful message.

In my AsyncTask B where I execute the install:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
boolean ret= viewmodel.installApk(mActivity);
return ret;
}
```

In my view model class:

```
public boolean installApk(Activity mActivity){
    boolean success = false;
    String fullPath = scanDirectoryForApk();

    System.out.println("INSTALLING APK ......................... ");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, mActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(fullPath));
    intent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
 }
```

However, when I execute the code above, no error message was shown and the version upgrade is not working as well. It basically just restart the intent and there is no upgrade at all.

It does not prompt me for the permission to install new version as well. Any ideas?

By the way, my android emulator is not rooted and therefore I could not use the "su" command approach.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

As suggestion by @Sagar, I changed my code above to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, mActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(fullPath));

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = mActivity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        mActivity.grantUriPermission(packageName, apkURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    intent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

And I am getting new error message from logcat:

```
Error staging apk from content URI
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{3883c8 9647:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a20} (pid=9647, uid=10020) that is not exported from UID 10085
```

The intent error message is telling me "There was a problem parsing package".

Comment: Do you see any errors in logcat? Have you checked my answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072638/fileuriexposedexception-in-android/50102119#50102119) for properly handling the file uri exposed exception?

Comment: @Sagar yeap I tried the same way. The only errors are: Requesting uid 10085 needs to declare permission android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES and Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: Declare `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` in your manifest, just like any other permission

Comment: @Sagar I am getting new error from the UI saying there is an error parsing the package. When I check the logcat, I am getting this: Error staging apk from content URI
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{df5eecd 6335:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a20} (pid=6335, uid=10020) that is not exported from UID 10085

Comment: Check you answer of Lim from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial)

Comment: @Sagar I see I see but where do I execute that chunk of code? Before I execute the install()?

Comment: Yeah. Do it before install

Comment: @Sagar I pasted in the code but it is still throwing me the same error message :( And the error saying there was an error parsing the package persist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172862/discussion-between-sagar-and-guest176969).

Comment: @sagar I think I know the problem already. It was due to this line: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); I managed to get to the install intent but the progress always get stuck

Comment: Were u able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to merge

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

into

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I met the same issue as you, and this solution rescued myself.