# Android runtime permission keep getting denied

Tags: java, android, permissions, runtime

I am trying to request runtime permission for my Android application. Here is my code:

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
String installPermission = Manifest.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES;
String writePermission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

@Click(R.id.buttonVersionUpgrade)
void buttonVersionUpgradeClicked(View v) {
    if (!checkPermission(installPermission)) {
        requestPermission(installPermission);
    }
    if (!checkPermission(writePermission)) {
        requestPermission(writePermission);
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission(String permission){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permission);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private void requestPermission(String permission){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission required for features to work.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, the code above keep showing permission denied without prompting the user for permission. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could permissions have been denied with the don’t ask again option?

Comment: Nope I don't think so. It is the first time I requested for permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {...}` is unnecessary since `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` already takes care of necessary backward compatibility.

> However, the code above keep showing permission denied without
>   prompting the user for permission.

This is because, `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` & `android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES` are not for use by third-party applications.

If you only request `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` then you should see the proper permission dialog.

Permission request is shown for the permissions whose protection level is `dangerous`. You can refer this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to determine the protection level. Refer this [permission overview document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html) for more details regarding permission levels and types

Comment: But then how can I request permission for install packages? Because when I try to install the package, it throws me an error message saying permission denied and therefore I needed to request for it

Comment: @guest176969 have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: May I know what is the goToMarket intent is for? Also, I tried the promptInstall intent but it does not explicitly request the user for permission

Comment: @guest176969 to redirect user to play store and allow him/her to download the app from play store

Comment: I have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789156/android-install-apk-programatically-not-working

Comment: @guest176969 you can try the answer which I have recommended and let me know if you face issues.

Comment: As in the hyperlink? I tried that one but it does not work that is why I am using the FileProvider approach

Comment: I removed the if statement but it still not prompting me for the permission

Comment: @guest176969 As I said, it won't prompt because those permissions are not meant for third party apps.

Comment: Do you mind to provide me with some example? What do you mean by intent, I am lost.

Comment: @guest176969 I mean, follow the SO that I have recommended and you have tried. Check the cause of issue on the other question. You can check my comment on your another question.

Comment: @guest176969  For the context for this question, the answer is what I have mentioned. If you think it was useful, then remember to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I had an error in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />
```

I had space after "**WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**". I deleted it, and everything is OK now.