# how to load local file into webview

Tags: android, file, kotlin, local-storage, android-webview

Im trying load this file into my webview but its not loading

file path is something like

- /data/user/0/com.xyzapp.app/cache/temp_file.docx //this is getpathhh

below is my code

first activity:-

```
 val browseintent = Intent(this, WebviewActivityNew::class.java)
                browseintent.putExtra("url", "file://"+getpathhh.toString())
                startActivity(browseintent)
```

second Activity:-

```
  val url = intent.extras!!.getString("url")
    webview_comp.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview_comp.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview_comp.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webview_comp.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview_comp.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview_comp.getSettings().setAppCachePath(url);
    webview_comp.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview_comp.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    url?.let { webview_comp.loadUrl(it) };
```

if i use Action_view

```
  val pdfOpenintent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                pdfOpenintent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(getpathhh), "*/*")
                try {
                    startActivity(pdfOpenintent)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                }
```

im getting crash as 'E/UncaughtException: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.xyzapp.app/cache/temp_file.docx exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()'

following what i have tried

```
 val pdfOpenintent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                pdfOpenintent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        applicationContext,
                        "com.xyzapp.app.provider",
                        getpathhh
                    ), "*/*")
                try {
                    startActivity(pdfOpenintent)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                }
```

Comment: Well... what goes wrong?

Comment: You did not google for `FileUriExposedException`? `Uri.fromFile(getpathhh` You cannot use Uri.fromFile() anymore. You have to use a `FileProvider`.

Comment: can paste some reference or make a new answer for me please @blackapps?

Comment: Google for `FileUriExposedException`.

Comment: `telling me file doesnt exist` Please post the used code in your post. I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @blackapps i have edited

Comment: Add: if ( !getpathhh.exists()) return; before you start the  intent.  Now what do you have? A pdf file? A docx file? And why not use the proper mime type? Which app did you choose that complains about a non existing fil?

Comment: @blackapps need help here--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004490/how-to-get-difference-between-two-calender-time

Comment: @IRONMAN is this issue fixed?

Comment: yess but need help here @JeelVankhede need help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168986/webview-encoding-format-issue

Answer (score 1):

> > /data/user/0/com.xyzapp.app/cache/temp_file.docx

A WebView is for .html documents.

It cannot display a .docx file.

Comment: then how can i load this file location??

Comment: You can use ACTION_VIEW and let the user select an app, from the list that appears, that can handle .docx files. Did you install such apps on your device? (I didn't).

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: please im getting crash

Comment: Catch that exception and your app will not crash.... ;-)

Comment: i have gone through this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50102119/12527104

but shown apps doesnt opened my doc/pdf

Comment: telling me file doesnt exist