# How to get difference between two calendar times

Tags: android, kotlin, time, calendar

I want to get the two calender time difference

my calender is

```
 val calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar1[Calendar.HOUR+1] = hour.toString().toInt()
    calendar1[Calendar.MINUTE] = minute.toString().toInt()
```

this is giving in 12 hours format Wed Nov 17 06:30:31 GMT+05:30 2021

current calender is:-

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar[Calendar.HOUR]=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)
    calendar[Calendar.MINUTE]=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

this is giving in 24 hours format Wed Nov 17 18:01:32 GMT+05:30 2021

how to get this calender in 12 hours format

thats why im having difficult in finding two calender difference

can anyone help?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? `calendar[Calendar.HOUR]=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)` You are getting the hour from the calendar and setting the hour of the calendar to that same hour, so it's doing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first calender you are using

`calendar1[Calendar.HOUR+1]` -> which will be equivalent to `calendar1[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]`

Here are the constants from Calendar class

```
public static final int HOUR = 10;
public static final int HOUR_OF_DAY = 11;
```

use `calendar1[Calendar.HOUR]` for 24 hour format .

Better way is to get millis from both calenders and find difference between 2 millis .

To get millis use `calendar.time.time`

for getting difference between millis see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940648/6478047)