# webview encoding format issue

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

i refering this answer --> [Send authorization header with every request in webview using okhttp in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440736/send-authorization-header-with-every-request-in-webview-using-okhttp-in-android)

but im getting something like this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i also tried text/html and html/plain but it didnt help

following is my code:-

```
   val wvc: WebViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, url: String): WebResourceResponse? {
        return try {
           // val acToken: String = pref.getString("token", "DEFAULT")
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
            val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $bearer").build()
            val response: Response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()
            WebResourceResponse(response.header("content-type", response.body()?.contentType()?.type()),  // You can set something other as default content-type
                response.header("content-encoding", "UTF-8"),  // Again, you can set another encoding as default
                response.body()?.byteStream()
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}
```

setting to webview

```
 webview_comp.setWebViewClient(wvc);
      
 url?.let { webview_comp.loadUrl(it) };
```

any help will thankful  here is the output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5trdD.png

Comment: Can you try this as return on try block: `WebResourceResponse("text/html", "utf-8", response.body()?.byteStream())`, Basically pass hard-coded strings for first two parameters and check whether issue is with that or not..

Comment: @JeelVankhede now it is showing combination of ??? and text

Comment: �����������������ot Entry�������� �F����WordD�4l�*0���Er� TS� � 2019 IJRAR February 2019, Volume 6, Issue 1

Comment: @JeelVankhede any idea ?

Comment: I think it has something to do with mime-type and encoding.. one thing I'd suggest is to pass only string of individuals rather than wrapping them into `response.header()`

Comment: You can try this variation also: `WebResourceResponse(response.body()?.contentType()?.type(), null, response.body()?.byteStream())`

Comment: it showing blank @JeelVankhede

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239694/discussion-between-jeel-vankhede-and-iron-man).