# Cannot copy file from SMB to phone internal memory

Tags: android, file, copy, smb

Hello fellow programmers, I have difficulties to copy file from Windows shared folder to phone internal memory. I investigated for hours but I am stucked on error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Download/example.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I have required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also those for Android 6.0 and above

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

            return;
        }
        else   {}


    }
```

Here is my what I do

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(DOMAIN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            SmbFile dir = null;


            try {
                //String PATH = "smb://192.168.8.100/share/";

                SmbFile source = new SmbFile(PATH+"example.pdf",auth);
                File destination = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "example.pdf");
                InputStream in = source.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                out.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Any ideas what I could do wrong?

Comment: The error says something about "Download/example.pdf" - and nothing to do with the SmbFile read (why is PATH commented out, what is the actual value? but that's secondary.. because it would throw the exception without any SMB-related code!). So track down why `new FileOutputStream(..)` is throwing the exception: **a 'clue' is that the path reported ("Download/..") is _relative and unqualified_**. The code [should probably do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472409) to turn it into a relevant *qualified path* (that, hopefully, exists).