# Deleting a directory and its contents in android

Tags: java, android

In an android app, I download a file from server. File is downloaded in `/downloads/store_downloads/file`.

**Problem**

I am trying to delete the `store_downloads` directory and all the files in it.

I wrote following code to do it.

```
File directory = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/store_downloads");

if(directory.exists()) {

     File[] allContents = directory.listFiles();

     if(allContents != null) {
          for (File subFile : allContents) {
               subFile.delete();
          }
     }

     directory.delete();
}
```

but `directory.exists` always returns false.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20472557/10136855 This comment may help you.

Comment: Also note that `directory.exists()` introduces a possible race condition. In between inter-opting with the file and that line it may have been removed/changed/something. Rule of thumb: If you are going to interact with a file right after doing some kind of 'file exists' check, the file exists check is redundant. Just catch the exception, if any.